# how to bind dataset with gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

This is my code .aspx.cs page

```
public string makequery()
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    if (ddlPortal2.SelectedValue == "Select" && tbFrom.Text == null && tbTo.Text == null && ddlQuery.SelectedValue == "Select")
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM Form3 and ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [Datetime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "' DESC";
        return query;
    }
    else if(ddlPortal2.SelectedItem.Text!="Select" && tbFrom.Text!=null && tbTo.Text!=null && ddlQuery.SelectedItem.Text=="Select")
    {
        query = "Select * from Form3 where Portal='" + ddlPortal2.SelectedValue + "' and ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [Datetime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "' DESC";
        return query;
    }
    else if (ddlPortal2.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" && tbFrom.Text == null && tbTo.Text == null && ddlQuery.SelectedItem.Text != "Select")
    {
        query = "Select * from Form3 where Portal='" + ddlPortal2.SelectedValue + "' and ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [Datetime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "' DESC";
        return query;
    }
    return null;
}
public void GridViewBind()
{
    string query = makequery();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    if (ds != null)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GridViewBind();
}
```

}
.aspx page code:

```
<div id="Portal" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblPortal" runat="server" Text="Select Portal"/>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPortal2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>TRAVELONG</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ONETRAVEL</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>.UK-BSP</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>.CV-YYZ</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>.CV-YVR</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:Label ID="lbFrom" Text="From" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbFrom" runat="server" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFrom" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbFrom" ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Date">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       <asp:Label ID="lblto" Text="To" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTo" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbTo" 
        ErrorMessage="Enter To date">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuery" runat="server" Width="87px">
           <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="Query ">Query</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>Non Query</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
    onclick="btnSearch_Click" ValidationGroup="1"/><br />

        <br />           
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
    </div>
<div id="Main" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <itemtemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="cmdBind"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID")%>' ID="ID" ToolTip='<%#Eval("ID")%>'>LinkButton                </asp:LinkButton>                                                                   
            </itemtemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateTime","{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>   
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Portal" HeaderText="Portal" SortExpression="Portal" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TID" HeaderText="TID" SortExpression="TID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PNR" HeaderText="PNR" SortExpression="PNR" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNumber" HeaderText="TicketNumber" SortExpression="TicketNumber" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unused Tkt Amount" SortExpression="ddlUnusedAmount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUnusedAmount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UnusedTicketAmount")+ "-" + Eval("ddlUnusedAmount")%>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Penality" SortExpression="ddlAirlinePenality" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAirlinePenality" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AirlinePenality")+ "-" + Eval("ddlAirlinePenality")%>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Refund" SortExpression="ddlNetRefundProcess" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNetRefund" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NetRefundProcess")+ "-" + Eval("ddlNetRefundProcess")%>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Refundable Commission"   SortExpression="ddlRefundableCommission" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRefundableCommission" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RefundableCommission")+ "-" + Eval("ddlRefundableCommission")%>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ESACCode" HeaderText="ESACCode" SortExpression="ESACCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WaiverCode" HeaderText="WaiverCode" SortExpression="WaiverCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundType" HeaderText="RefundType" SortExpression="RefundType" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Bart Comment" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Query" HeaderText="ARC Verified" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </Columns>
```

Now here I make two function one to make query and second to bind that query with `dataset` with `gridview` when I bind `dataset` Cannot find table 0.

what I want is when I select field and press search button I can view details in my grid according to the selected fields but I can't bind it with my `dataset`. Can you guys help me with this.

Comment: you havnt executed the query and got result in dataset. when you make query them hit the database and get result in dataset and then bind the dataset to gridview\

Comment: i use dataset ds=executenonquery.ReturnDataset(query); but it say executenonquey in not present in this context

Comment: "executenonquey" whats that? where it comes from? is it "executenonqueRy" you have a connection class?

Comment: can u tell me how to execute my query and then bind it with gridview using datatable

Comment: see the answer below.. Dave Rook has explained it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just make small changes in you code like as below

```
public string makequery()
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    if (ddlPortal2.SelectedValue == "Select" && tbFrom.Text == null && tbTo.Text == null && ddlQuery.SelectedValue == "Select")
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM Form3 and ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [Datetime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "' DESC";
        return query;
    }
    else if(ddlPortal2.SelectedItem.Text!="Select" && tbFrom.Text!=null && tbTo.Text!=null && ddlQuery.SelectedItem.Text=="Select")
    {
        query = "Select * from Form3 where Portal='" + ddlPortal2.SelectedValue + "' and ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [Datetime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "' DESC";
        return query;
    }
    else if (ddlPortal2.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" && tbFrom.Text == null && tbTo.Text == null && ddlQuery.SelectedItem.Text != "Select")
    {
        query = "Select * from Form3 where Portal='" + ddlPortal2.SelectedValue + "' and ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [Datetime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "' DESC";
        return query;
    }
    return null;
}
public void GridViewBind()
{
    string query = makequery();
    sqlconnection con=new sqlconnection("Your Connection string"); 

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   SqlDataAdapter ad= new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);

   ad.fill(ds);

    if (ds != null)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GridViewBind();
}
```

Comment: You should check the row count from the query instead of the data table. It's faster.

Answer (score 2):

You need some extra code like this

```
private DataSet GetDataset(string query) 
{
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection connection = 
        new SqlConnection(connectionDetailsGoHere))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        connection.Close();
    }
        return dataset;
}

public void GridViewBind()
{
    string query = makequery();
    DataSet ds = GetDataset(query); // Updated
    if (ds != null)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Your queries look to be in-accurate too and probably won't execute. For 1, you can't have `AND` directly before `ORDER BY`

Your query is actually muddled, you've tried to order by a condition, this is actually incorrect. You want to use the `WHERE` clause instead.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Form3 WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [Datetime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "' ORDER BY [Datetime] DESC";
```

I think [this site will help you with SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) and [this site with DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)

Comment: thanks dave for your reply there is an error inmy query when i run that query in my sqlserver in work fine but when i use ORDER BY here it won't it say's error near order keyword can you tell me why this give such an error

Comment: yes but when i select from query dropdown list it won't work sry for late reply

Comment: @amitesh Try removing the where cause (where you are checking the date) from the SQL and see if that at least populates the dropdownlist for you.

Comment: i am edit my ques and give u my .aspx code and .aspx.sc code tell me where i was wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27622/discussion-between-amitesh-and-dave-rook)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it:

```
private DataTable LoadData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionStringName"].ToString());
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "yourProcName";

    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(dt);
    connection.Close();

    return dt;
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = this.LoadData();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Modify the above code to suit your needs. I have used `stored procedure` to load data, you can use `inline` query too. Just modify these two line if you want to use `inline` query.

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM yourTable";
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your queries use 'AND order by yourColumns'. I don't think an 'AND' is necessary. It works this way (notice there is no AND)

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB from yourTable where ColumnA='abc' order by ColumnB
```

Also, you are not executing the query so there are no results.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was problem. Background color of the  gridview was the same as the letters color so it wasn't visible because of that..... **I am sorry because I disturbed you because of that simple thing....**

Answer (score 0):

This also works, really simple

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
```

No need to set any other parameter for a desktop application. This will populate column names also.